# How to set default file extension of saving file for specific syntax in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

The C++ standard doesn't rule the file extension, so the most of people use `.cpp`, but I prefer using `.cc`, how to tell Sublime Text save to `.cc` when using C++ syntax as default?

Comment: The easiest way (seriously) is to simply manually type the extension when you're saving the file. That eliminates having to unpack system files and change them, possibly introducing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to change the default file extension shown by the *save-as* dialog when saving a file set to a specific syntax is to override that syntax's default `.sublime-syntax` file. In your case that would be the `C++.sublime-syntax` file.

Of course, as *MattDMo* points out, the easiest thing to do is to manually type the preferred file extension whenever you save a file. But for those that want to make the change, here's how to do it.

- Open the `Command Palette` and select `View Package File`.
- Type `C++` and then select `C++/C++.sublime-syntax`. ST will open the file.
- Near the top you should see `file_extensions:` and a list like this:

```
file_extensions:
  - cpp
  - cc
  - cp
  - cxx
  - c++
  ...snip...
```

- ST uses the 1st item in the `file_extensions` list as the default file extension for the save-as dialog.
- To make `.cc` the default extension instead of `.cpp`, edit the list order so that `- cc` is the 1st item and `- cpp` is 2nd, i.e. swap the top 2 lines around.
- Now save the file in your ST config `Packages` directory with this path: `../Packages/C++/C++.sublime-syntax`. If you like you can create a `C++` directory in `Packages` and then just use `Ctrl+S` to save because the path will have been automatically set by ST but the file won't save unless the `../Packages/C++/` directory already exists.
- Note: The full path on a Linux machine would be like this: `/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/C++/C++.sublime-syntax`
- The [Package Resource Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin's `Open Resource` Command Palette command could be used to extract `.sublime-syntax` files instead of ST's native `View Package File` command. That plugin will automatically create the appropriate `Packages` directory when necessary.

Your altered `Packages/C++/C++.sublime-syntax` file will now override the default version that is shipped with ST. You can reverse this easily simply by deleting the file. It is safe to delete the directory as well if you are not overriding any other files in the same directory.

The only problem with this is when you install a new version of ST. If the newly installed version has an updated `C++.sublime-syntax` file, the local one you've created will continue to override the new one. To get around this delete your altered `Packages/C++/C++.sublime-syntax` file when you install a new version of ST and repeat the steps above to restore your preferred default file extension once the installation has been done.

Unfortunately there is no way around this, you can not partially override the `C++.sublime-syntax` file with just the `file_extensions:` section. Of course new versions of ST don't come along very frequently and the `C++.sublime-syntax` file gets updated even less often. So this is not a major issue.

Comment: This may work for super power users (like me), but for the vast majority of users just typing in the desired `.cc` when you're saving the file for the first time is by far the easiest method. It doesn't involve editing system files and potentially introducing errors there.

Comment: Note also that just doing a `Save` won't work unless the user also manually creates a `C++` folder in `Packages`; although the loaded file has the correct path, that path is not necessarily reflected on disk.

Comment: @MattDMo You are absolutely right, the easiest way to do it is to type it every time. But I think it is safe to assume that anyone who is writing C++ code knows how to save a file with whatever file extension they want. Alan asked the question and I told him how to do it and pointed out the downside of overriding the file. Are you actually criticising me for answering the question? Cos that's what "*This may work for super power users...*" sounds like to me. And Matt people only become power users by learning - for example by reading about advanced configuration of syntax files.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks you're right - I got muddled with the [Package Resource Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin's `Open Resource` feature which does automatically create the directory when necessary. My test yesterday worked because I already had a `Packages/C++/` folder. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @mattst No, I wasn't criticizing you for answering, I guess I was more taking issue with the fact that you said up front "*The only way to do this is to...*". It's a good answer, and I've definitely written my fair share of "power user only" answers on this site. Cheers!

Comment: @MattDMo I've re-worded the opening paragraphs. :)

Comment: @mattst Aww, I even get a shout-out. Thanks :)